# Multidimensional array (parent and childs)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, nested

I have a category system in a MySQL database with parents and childs. The database only stores  the id of it''s immediate parent (or 0 if on root). Since the system allows multiple subcategories there are cases of multiple childs.

For example

```
[98] Storage
    [1] External
        [3] Pendrives
        [4] Portable hhdds
    [2] Internal
        [5] Sata hhdd
        [6] IDE hhdd
[...]
[99] Clothing
```

The database would be

```
id    parent_id    name
1     98           External
2     98           Internal
3     1            Pendrives
4     1            Portable
5     2            Sata
6     2            IDE
98    0            Storage
99    0            Clothing
```

I also have a products table with a category id and I need to get a list of all the products in the first level of categories.

For example:

```
Product   Category
 A          3
 B          4
 C          5
 D          6
 E          74
```

Should return
98: A, B, C, D
99: X, Y, Z...

I'm stuck and I can't think of the logic to retrieve it in that way.

I started by getting the IDs of all the categories that aren't in the first level by:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['parent_id'] != 0) {
        $level1[$i]['name'] = utf8_encode($row['categories_name']);
        $level1[$i]['id'] = $row['categories_id'];
    }

    $i++;
}
```

but I'm having a burnout and can't think of a way that would nest them. I thought some kind of while but it's infinite :P

Any ideas please?

Comment: This is where `1NF` makes task easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive function to get all child categories:

```
//fetch category structure data
$childCategories = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, parent_id FROM categories");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['parent_id']) {
        if (!isset($childCategories[$row['parent_id']])) $childCategories[$row['parent_id']] = array();
        $childCategories[$row['parent_id']][] = $row['id'];
    }
}

function getRecursiveCategories($id, $childCategories) {
    $ret = array();
    if (!isset($childCategories[$id])) return $ret;
    foreach ($childCategories[$id] as $childId) {
        $ret[] = $childId;
        $ret = array_merge($ret, getRecursiveCategories($childId, $childCategories));
    }
    return $ret;
}

$cateoryIds = getRecursiveCategories(98, $childCategories);

//now you can query the products
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id IN (".implode(',', $cateoryIds).")";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about recursive function calling? For example:

```
$allItems = Array();
function getAllItems($category) {
    global $allItems;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `categories` WHERE `parent_id` = '".$category."' ");

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)) {
        while($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $itemQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `category` = '".$cat['id']."' ");
            if(mysql_num_rows($itemQuery)) {
                while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($itemQuery)) {
                    $allItems[$item['id']] = $item; //using $item['id'] to avoid duplicating items if they are in several categories
                }
            }
            $checkSubCatQuery = "SELECT `id` FROM `categories` WHERE `parent_id` = '".$cat['id']."' LIMIT 1");
            if(mysql_num_rows($checkSubCatQuery)) { //Checking to see if we have a sub category
                getAllItems($cat['id']); //Calling agait to get all items from sub cattegory of the current category
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ofcourse it can always be optimised.

Comment: This would generate a query per child category which is exaclty what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I know one perfect [article](http://php.vrana.cz/traverzovani-kolem-stromu-prakticky.php) on how to do this correctly and with good performance in mysql (*I cannot take any credit for the idea, I'm just translating it from Czech*).

[image: Database layout]

You'll need tree structure like this:

```sql
categories (
    id,
    lft,  -- index on "left iteration" - number on the left
    rgt,  -- index on "right iteration" - number on the right
    depth,
)
```

#### How to display a complete tree:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY lft");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo str_repeat("- ", $row["depth"]) . htmlspecialchars($row["data"]) . "<br />";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

If you need to print a whole tree it's enough to sort it by `lft` and write it down. If you need to display just part of tree, you can limit both `lft` and `rft` do be greater then current node values.

#### Showing in ordered list:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY lft");
$depth = -1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($depth < $row["depth"]) {
        echo "<ul>";
    } else {
        echo str_repeat("</li></ul>", $depth - $row["depth"]) . "</li>";
    }
    echo "<li>\n" . htmlspecialchars($row["data"]);
    $depth = $row["depth"];
}
echo str_repeat("</li></ul>", $depth + 1) . "\n";
mysql_free_result($result);
```

When displaying in ordered list (with multiple levels) you have to detect connection between current nodes `depth` and the next items.

#### Getting it for a "breadcrumbs navigation":

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = " . intval($_GET["id"])));
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE lft < $row[lft] AND rgt > $row[rgt] ORDER BY lft");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    echo "<a href='?id=$row1[id]'>" . htmlspecialchars($row1["data"]) . "</a> &gt; ";
}
mysql_free_result($result1);
echo htmlspecialchars($row["data"]);
```

#### Add child to the end of the list:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (lft, rgt, depth, data)
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(rgt), 0) + 1, IFNULL(MAX(rgt), 0) + 2, 0, '" .         
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["data"]) . "' FROM categories");
```

#### Add a child node to wherever you need

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = " . intval($_GET["rodic"]) . " FOR UPDATE"));
mysql_query("UPDATE categories SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > $row[rgt]");
mysql_query("UPDATE categories SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt >= $row[rgt]");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (lft, rgt, depth, data) VALUES ($row[rgt], $row[rgt]+1, $row[depth]+1, '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["data"]) . "')");
mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

#### Remove complete child

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = " . intval($_GET["id"]) . " FOR UPDATE"));
mysql_query("DELETE FROM categories WHERE lft >= $row[lft] AND rgt <= $row[rgt]");
$rozdil = $row["rgt"] - $row["lft"] + 1;
mysql_query("UPDATE categories SET lft = lft - $rozdil WHERE lft > $row[rgt]");
mysql_query("UPDATE categories SET rgt = rgt - $rozdil WHERE rgt > $row[rgt]");
mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

<sub>If you know any more info (or name) for this algorithm, please let me know</sub>

*I recommend to write this using PDO.*

Comment: thanks but I can't modify the db because it's a working system developed by someone else, I'm just plugging in

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps below should do the trick (the algorithm can be improved for efficiency):

- First do a select based on the initial category ID. Something like `SELECT id, parent_id FROM categories` store the results in an array like:

  ```
  $catArr = array(
     array(1,98),
     array(2,98),
     ...
    );
  ```
- Run this against the following function (note: $start=98)

  ```
  function getSubsets($catArr, $start) {
     $rtn = array();
     foreach($catArr as $cat) {
        if($cat[1] == $start) { 
           $rtn[] = $cat[0];
           $subcats = getSubsets($catArr,$cat[0]);
           foreach($subcats as $subcat) { $rtn[] = $subcat; }
        }
     }
     return $rtn;
  }

  note: never have a category be its own parent or any other similar 
  conditions that would cause an infinite loop.
  ```
- Now your final SQL can be generated like this

  ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category IN (".implode(',', $rtn).")"; 
   Note: this assumes category is a number
  ```

Final Note: you only run two SQL queries :)